# How do I define possible return values with Swagger.io

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have an API call whose response includes a status field with a large number of potential status codes. These codes are numeric and thus not self-explanatory.

Using Swagger.io how can I provide a table of these status codes with their corresponding description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's where the GFM in the description comes in handy. Just add a table to the description and that's it.

Comment: Is GFM markdown?  I must have missed that in the documentation.

Comment: Answering my own question...from the documentation: "GFM syntax can be used for rich text representation."  GFM being GitHub Flavored Mardown.  https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/